# How to delete wrong tag that was created by accident?

Tags: support

I created a tag **shorting-lending** that I want to delete, but could not.

Answer (score 2):

Now that it has no questions, it'll be [cleaned up automatically after a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112519/empty-tags-with-no-questions).